# Displaying values in 3-4 columns and 3 rows

Tags: php

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_food WHERE food_cat='soup'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo"<tr>
<td><img src='".$row['picture']."' onclick='addtocart(".$row['food_id'].")' /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>    <b>".$row['name']."</b><br />
 Price:<big style='color:green'>
 $".$row['price']."</big><br /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><hr size='1' /></td>";
} ?>
```

I've been working on an ordering system for our thesis and I'm stuck with these columns and rows. I'm not sure how I'm going to manipulate the values or the table.

Comment: Can you be clear? Give us the table structure, let us know what you want? And what are you getting in your existing code?

Comment: if only i could make it display in manner like 
r1c1|r1c2|r1c3|r1c4
r2c1|r2c2|r2c3|r2c4
and all i've been getting is that all values are displayed in a single row.

Comment: To be frank, no way we can understand the code. Do this. Get the table dump, and create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 1):

try with code

```
    <?php
   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_food WHERE food_cat='soup'");
  echo "<table>";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
 <tr>
 <td><img src='<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>' onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['food_id'];?>)" /></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td>    <b><?php echo $row['name'];?></b><br />
 Price:<big style='color:green'>
 <?php echo $row['price'] ;?></big><br /><br />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td colspan='2'><hr size='1' /></td></tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?> 
</table>
```